# GNU libc on windows and MINGW

Tags: c, compatibility

Why cant we use gnu libc on windows?
is ms visual c++ runtime(msvcrt) the windows equivalent to glibc?

I know that we need MINGW to use gcc compiler on windows, but what exactly is Mingw doing here(How is it making gcc run on windows)?

Comment: Because it calls some Linux-specific functions that don't exist on Windows. There are ports that will run on Windows.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/37862205/

Comment: The guys are [WinLibs](https://www.winlibs.com/) have created a tidy bundle for GCC and MinGW for those unfortunate enough to have to write for Windows.  Download the appropriate version, unpack and set your PATH. Sorted!